# Can I use $(this) in a jquery.data() call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to store the default value of an element in that element's `jQuery.data()` collection.  Since I can't do this...

```
$("#myElement").data('defaultValue', $(this).html());
```

... because `$(this)` does not give me a reference to `#myElement`, what is the most efficient way to do this?  I'm trying to avoid selecting the element twice like this:

```
$("#myElement").data('defaultValue', $("#myElement").html());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *sane* way really other than to save the jQuery object in a temporary variable:

```
var $element = $("#myElement");
$element.data('defaultValue', $element.html());
```

An altenative which is just one expression, but IMHO is much worse:

```
$("#myElement").each(function() { $(this).data('defaultValue', $(this).html()); });
```

Comment: You left off the closing paren to your `.each` fn (**update** I fixed it ^_^)

Answer (score 1):

Ehhh.

You could try to hack around it:

```
$("#myElement").each(function(){$(this).data('defaultValue', $(this).html());});
```

## UGLY

Or do like the other posts:

```
var $element = $("#myElement");
$element.data('defaultValue', $element.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = $("#myElement");
el.data('defaultValue', el.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myElement = $("#myElement");
myElement.data('defaultValue', myElement.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a performance freak, you could save nano seconds by saving a reference to #myElement:

```
var $myElement = $("#myElement");
$myElement.data('defaultValue', $myElement.html());
```